# Delphi Circular unit reference

Tags: delphi

I have a problem of circular reference between class. Here is the error:

> [dcc32 Fatal Error] StackWeb.MessageClassHelper.pas(5): F2047 Circular unit reference to 'StackWeb.MessageClass'

I'd like to use both class in different units.

How could I solve it?

```
unit StackWeb.MessageClass;

interface

uses
  StackWeb.ChatItemClass,

type    
  TMessageClass = class(TCardDefault)
  private
    FChat : TChatItemClass;
  public
    property chat : TChatItemClass read FChat write FChat;
  end;
```

```
unit StackWeb.ChatItemClass;

interface

uses
  StackWeb.MessageClass;

type    
  TChatItemClass = class(TClassStandardList<TMessageClass>)
  private
    FMessages : TArray<TMessageClass>;
  public
    property messages : TArray<TMessageClass> read FMessages write FMessages;
  end;
```

Comment: The only way you're able to successfully have a circular referenced unit is if one of them use "used" from the `implementation` section instead of the `interface`.

Comment: @Jerry Dodge I can´t do it, because I need to use in the interface section

Comment: @LuizAlves a *forward declaration* is the ONLY way to break circular unit dependancy without otherwise redesigning your classes to not depend on each other at all

Answer (score 1):

The *declaration* of the `TMessageClass` class does not need to know the specifics of how the `TChatItemClass` class is declared, only that it is a class type, so use a **forward declaration** to break the circular unit dependancy of the two `interface` sections, eg:

```pascal
unit StackWeb.MessageClass;

interface

{uses
  StackWeb.ChatItemClass;}

type
  TChatItemClass = class; // <-- HERE

  TMessageClass = class(TCardDefault)
  private
    FChat : TChatItemClass;
  public
    property chat : TChatItemClass read FChat write FChat;
  end;

implementation

uses
  StackWeb.ChatItemClass; // <-- MOVED HERE

...

end.
```

```pascal
unit
  StackWeb.ChatItemClass;

interface

uses
  StackWeb.MessageClass;

type
  TChatItemClass = class(TClassStandardList<TMessageClass>)
  private
    FMessages : TArray<TMessageClass>;
  public
    property messages : TArray<TMessageClass> read FMessages write FMessages;
  end;

...

end.
```

This scenario is actually covered in Delphi's documentation:

[Classes and Objects (Delphi): Forward Declarations and Mutually Dependent Classes](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Classes_and_Objects_(Delphi)#Forward_Declarations_and_Mutually_Dependent_Classes)

> If the declaration of a class type ends with the word `class` and a semicolon - that is, if it has the form
>
> ```
> type className = class;
> ```
>
> with no ancestor or class members listed after the word `class`, then it is a forward declaration. A forward declaration must be resolved by a defining declaration of the same class within the same type declaration section. In other words, between a forward declaration and its defining declaration, nothing can occur except other type declarations.
>
> Forward declarations allow mutually dependent classes. For example:
>
> ```pascal
> type
>   TFigure = class; // forward declaration
>   TDrawing = class
>     Figure: TFigure;
>     // ...
>   end;
>
>   TFigure = class // defining declaration
>     Drawing: TDrawing;
>     // ...
>   end;
> ```
>
> Do not confuse forward declarations with complete declarations of types that derive from System.TObject without declaring any class members.
>
> ```pascal
> type
>   TFirstClass = class; // this is a forward declaration
>
>   TSecondClass = class // this is a complete class declaration
>   end;
>
>   TThirdClass = class(TObject); // this is a complete class declaration
> ```

Comment: @Remy Lebeau  Thank you Remy, but It does not working.  I get  [dcc32 Error] StackWeb.ChatItemClass.pas(10): E2086 Type 'TMessageClass' is not yet completely defined

Comment: @LuizAlves well, that is because you are using `TMessageClass` inside of Generics, which don't work on partial types. I updated my answer. You should only need the forward declaration on the non-Generic side to break the circular unit dependancy.

Comment: @ Remy Lebeau  I am using different units to classes. Your post doent work to me.  I already read about embarcadero notes abou it . All links posted from  David does not solve my problem

Comment: @remy No. The code doesn't compile because you have a forward definition which you fail to define later in that type section.